Issue with getLeaderSchedule RPC method in Solana when passing epoch parameter
Issue with getLeaderSchedule RPC method in Solana when passing epoch parameter
I'm trying to use the Solana JSON RPC API's getLeaderSchedule method to retrieve the leader schedule for a specific epoch and validator. Below is the code snippet I'm using:
async function getLeaderSchedule() {
  const url = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com';
  let epoch = 713; 
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "getLeaderSchedule",
    params: [
      epoch, 
      {
        identity: "BNtHBLo1L2vAG7PBQ6mJvWz7GqVPxBnioXsY2Gjtubrg" // Validator identity
      }
    ]
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
}


However, when I pass the epoch parameter (e.g., epoch = 713),
its response is
{ jsonrpc: '2.0', result: null, id: 1 }
When I omit the epoch parameter (leave it null), the method works fine and returns the leader schedule for the current epoch.
Does the getLeaderSchedule method only work for the current epoch, or should it support historical epochs as well?
Are there specific conditions or limitations for fetching leader schedules for past epochs?

Looking at the implementation for the getLeaderSchedule RPC endpoint at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/c7131f627f3b249a5756b26d9a2ac6e40bcfa5ea/rpc/src/rpc.rs#L2925-L2957, it appears that it accepts a slot parameter. Essentially, you can only get the leader schedule for a few epochs, based on the given slot, not epoch.
The cache, however, only keeps 10 total epochs, which means that you can typically only query 8 epochs backwards, since you can also query the current epoch and the next one.
